# How to make CLion accept gtest syntax?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, ubuntu, googletest, clion

I am not able to make CLion understand gtest syntax so it gives me syntax errors when writing a

```
TEST_P(MyParamFixtureTest, MyTestName) { ... }
```

I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145887/why-no-library-files-installed-for-google-test).

Answer (score 0):

Eventually fixed it by doing this:

```
# install gtest dev
sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev

# build static libraries
cd /usr/src/gtest
sudo cmake .
sudo make
sudo mv libg* /usr/lib/
```

Comment: So you've basically solved it by doing the exact same thing that is specified by the link from your question?! This looks like an attempt to gain reputation by answering your own question ...